# Connecting Maria db 10.2 to magento 2.3.5

Tags: setup-upgrade, mariadb

I have website to connected database
I am using RDS MARIAB 10.2
while running upgrade command faced :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable), query was: CREATE  
   TRIGGER trg_catalog_compare_item_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_compare_item FOR EACH ROW                                                                                                            
  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  INSERT INTO m2_cl_catalog_compare_item (`catalog_compare_item_id`, `operation`) VALUES (NEW.catalog_compare_item_id, 'INSERT')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operation = 'INSERT';                                 
  END
```

[image: error]

any solution??

Comment: Check if the database user has assigned all privilege or permission for change in database

Comment: my user is not assigned SUPER privilledge

Comment: If i try to assign all privilege then still it gives error

Comment: Please refer this as well - http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/troubleshooting-guide/mysql/import/binary-logging#:~:text=The%20error%20arises%20when%20you,on%20for%20the%20MySQL%20server.

Comment: writing this command it say you do not have super user privilege : SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

Comment: Then just ask your server team to look into this